# Multidimensional Character Array

Tags: c++, arrays

How do you initialize and Uninitialize a multidimensional character array in C++?

Comment: Depends on the language. And what do you mean by uninitialize?

Comment: I must be blind, you already specified in C++ :S

Comment: The homework tag is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Read the [**FAQ**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.16) -- you'll find everything you need there!

**Creation:**

Statically allocated:

```
char mda[ dim1_size ][ dim2_size ]...[ dimn_size ];
```

Dynamically allocated: Nested `new[]` calls.

**Initialization:**

Nested for loops; as many `for` as your dimensions.

**Unitialization:** Do you mean Destruction?

Statically allocated: The compiler does this when the stack frame is unwound (or for global variables -- when the program stops running).

Dynamically allocated:

```
Using nested delete[].
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the Boost.Multi_Array library.
The dimension of the array has to be provided at compile-time, but the sizes are only used at runtime.
That means that you have the advantages of dynamic allocation without the pain of having to deal with memory issues.

Here goes the example from the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).

```
int 
main () {
  // Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
  typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;
  array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);

  // Assign values to the elements
  int values = 0;
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
      for(index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
        A[i][j][k] = values++;

  // Verify values
  int verify = 0;
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
      for(index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
        assert(A[i][j][k] == verify++);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting, **and** this requires a serious look.

The answer given by roo is a widely used one, but I like his observation -  *just because it compiles doesn't mean it works*

I would think a better solution would be to allocate a contigious block of memory (rows * cols) long and then treat it as a 2D array?

Comment: It would be interesting to allocate a contiguous block of memory but, by doing so, you lose any possibility of changing the size of your array in every dimension.

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize a multidimensional array like this:

```
int grid[2][3] = {1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6};
```

in that case the seperate values would be:

```
grid[0, 0]: 1
grid[0, 1]: 3
grid[0, 2]: 5
grid[1, 0]: 2
grid[1, 1]: 4
grid[1, 2]: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick snippet - it compiles in g++.

```
int rows = 10;
int cols = 10;

char** array = new char*[rows];
for( int i = 0; i < cols; ++i ) {
  array[i] = new char[cols];
}

//do stuff with array

for( int i = 0; i < cols; ++i ) {
  delete array[i];
}
delete array;
```

Comment: Oh my god this is awful. This is C with a C++ disguise !

Answer (score 0):

I learned it with a tic tac toe board

```
const int ROW = 3;
const int COLUMN = 3;
char board [ROW] [COLUMN] = {{'O', 'X', 'O'},
                             {'X', 'X', 'X'},
                             {'X', 'O', 'X'}};
```

I hope this helped.